# Flat file document database with recursion

Tags: database, nosql

I am looking for a database similar to Sqlite in terms of usability, but that stores one single document instead. That is, basic data like integers, floats, bytes, and also lists and dictionaries(similar to JSON). It must be possible to extend these lists and dicts efficiently with little performance loss for a big and high depth document and without requiring to overwrite the complete document. I originally looked at the Sqlite JSON1 extension, but this does not seem efficient when inserting often in a big document. Other ideas were `lmdb` and `unqlite`, but as far as I understand they function as key-value store and don't allow for sub-documents.

I will be using this to store the (dynamic) intermediate results of a process, which contains sub-processes for which I also want to store the results as a member of their parent document. Preferably with unbounded depth. My language is `python`. The complete document will be too big to entirely fit in RAM.